# Changing macro from loop through to sheet 1

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following macro, but it loops through all active sheets which Id like to change to sheet 1 only and not column H, the reason is that I am changing the names of the countries but the macro also changes the nationality which I don't want. for example when it changes Africa to 719 which is correct it also changes African to 719an.
I would be grateful for any help.

```
Sub Multi_FindReplace()


Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long

fndList = Array("Libya", "New Caledonia", "St Vincent and the Grenadines", "Tanzania Untd Republic of", "Liechtenstein", "New Zealand", "Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "Thailand", "Lithuania")
rplcList = Array("434", "540", "670", "834", "438", "554", "666", "764", "440")
fndList = Array("Nicaragua", "Samoa", "Timor -Leste", "Luxembourg", "Niger", "San Marino", "Togo", "Macao", "Nigeria", "Sao Tome And Principe", "Tokelau")
rplcList = Array("558", "882", "626", "442", "562", "674", "768", "446", "566", "678", "772")
fndList = Array("Macedonia the former Yugoslav Republic of", "Niue", "Saudi Arabia", "Tonga", "Madagascar", "Norfolk Island", "Senegal", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Malawi", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Serbia", "Tunisia")
rplcList = Array("807", "570", "682", "776", "450", "574", "686", "780", "454", "580", "688", "788")
fndList = Array("Malaysia", "Norway", "Seychelles", "Turkey", "Maldives", "Oman", "Sierra Leone", "Turkmenistan", "Mali", "Pakistan", "Singapore", "Turks and Caicos Islands", "Malta", "Palau", "Sint Martin (Dutch part)", "Tuvalu", "Marshall Islands", "Palestine, State of")
rplcList = Array("458", "578", "690", "792", "462", "512", "694", "795", "466", "586", "702", "796", "470", "585", "534", "798", "584", "275")
fndList = Array("Slovakia", "Uganda", "Martinique", "Panama", "Slovenia", "Ukraine", "Mauritania", "Papua New Guinea", "Solomon Islands", "United Arab Emirates")
rplcList = Array("703", "800", "474", "591", "705", "804", "478", "598", "90", "784")
fndList = Array("Mauritius", "Paraguay", "Somalia", "United Kingdom", "Mayotte", "Peru", "South Africa", "United States", "Mexico", "Philippines", "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands")
rplcList = Array("480", "600", "706", "826", "175", "604", "710", "840", "484", "608", "239")
fndList = Array("US Minor Outlying Islands", "Micronesia Federated States of", "Pitcairn", "South Sudan", "Unknown", "Moldova", "Poland", "Spain", "Uruguay", "Monaco", "Portugal", "Sri Lanka", "Uzbekistan")
rplcList = Array("581", "583", "612", "728", "999", "498", "616", "724", "858", "492", "620", "144", "860")
fndList = Array("Mongolia", "Puerto Rico", "St Helena Ascension & Tristan da Cunha", "Vanuatu", "Montenegro", "Qatar", "Sudan", "Venezuela", "Montserrat", "Reunion", "Suriname", "Viet Nam")
rplcList = Array("496", "630", "654", "548", "499", "634", "736", "862", "500", "638", "740", "704")
fndList = Array("Morocco", "Romania", "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "Virgin Islands British", "Myanmar", "Russian Federation", "Swaziland", "Virgin Islands U.S.", "Mozambique", "Rwanda", "Sweden", "Wallis and Futuna", "Namibia", "Saint Barthelemy")
rplcList = Array("504", "642", "744", "92", "104", "643", "748", "850", "508", "646", "752", "876", "516", "652")
fndList = Array("Switzerland", "Western Sahara", "Nauru", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Syrian Arab Republic", "Yemen", "Nepal", "Saint Lucia", "Taiwan Province of China", "Zambia", "Netherlands", "Saint Martin (French part)", "Tajikistan", "Zimbabwe")
rplcList = Array("756", "732", "520", "659", "760", "887", "524", "662", "158", "894", "528", "663", "762", "716")

'Loop through each item in Array lists
  For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
    'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook
      For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
          LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
      Next sht

  Next x



End Sub
```

Comment: This line: `For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` may be the culprit.

Comment: Have you seen _[THIS](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-ways-to-reference-excel-workbooks-and-sheets-using-vba/)_

Comment: If you're having issues with `Africa` vs `African` VBA Regex may be of good use.

Comment: Thank you for quick response, what should I change he line For each sht in Activeworkbook.Worksheets too, sorry macros really not my bag. also can I exclude column H and if so how.

Comment: thank you for links will defo look at these

Comment: How is your country data setup on the worksheet?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with the current script. The fact that you reference *Sht.Cells* is going to include ALL cells, as well as the statements in the beginning of your sub, the arrays are overwritten. 
When the code executes, all you will have in the fndList is:

```
Array("Switzerland", "Western Sahara", "Nauru", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Syrian Arab Republic", "Yemen", "Nepal", "Saint Lucia", "Taiwan Province of China", "Zambia", "Netherlands", "Saint Martin (French part)", "Tajikistan", "Zimbabwe")
```

These should be consolidated to just one statement for fndList and one for rplcList:

```
fndList = Array("Libya", "New Caledonia", "St Vincent and the Grenadines", "Tanzania Untd Republic of", "Liechtenstein", _
"New Zealand", "Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "Thailand", "Lithuania", "Nicaragua", "Samoa", "Timor -Leste", "Luxembourg", _
"Niger", "San Marino", "Togo", "Macao", "Nigeria", "Sao Tome And Principe", "Tokelau", _
"Macedonia the former Yugoslav Republic of", "Niue", "Saudi Arabia", "Tonga", "Madagascar", "Norfolk Island", "Senegal", _
"Trinidad and Tobago", "Malawi", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Serbia", "Tunisia", "Malaysia", "Norway", "Seychelles", _
"Turkey", "Maldives", "Oman", "Sierra Leone", "Turkmenistan", "Mali", "Pakistan", "Singapore", "Turks and Caicos Islands", "Malta", "Palau", "Sint Martin (Dutch part)", "Tuvalu", "Marshall Islands", "Palestine, State of", "Slovakia", "Uganda", "Martinique", "Panama", "Slovenia", "Ukraine", "Mauritania", "Papua New Guinea", "Solomon Islands", "United Arab Emirates", "Mauritius", "Paraguay", "Somalia", "United Kingdom", "Mayotte", "Peru", "South Africa", _
"United States", "Mexico", "Philippines", "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "US Minor Outlying Islands", "Micronesia Federated States of", "Pitcairn", "South Sudan", "Unknown", "Moldova", "Poland", "Spain", "Uruguay", "Monaco", "Portugal", "Sri Lanka", "Uzbekistan", "Mongolia", "Puerto Rico", "St Helena Ascension & Tristan da Cunha", "Vanuatu", "Montenegro", "Qatar", "Sudan", "Venezuela", "Montserrat", "Reunion", "Suriname", "Viet Nam", _
"Morocco", "Romania", "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "Virgin Islands British", "Myanmar", "Russian Federation", "Swaziland", "Virgin Islands U.S.", "Mozambique", "Rwanda", "Sweden", "Wallis and Futuna", "Namibia", "Saint Barthelemy", "Switzerland", "Western Sahara", "Nauru", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Syrian Arab Republic", "Yemen", "Nepal", "Saint Lucia", "Taiwan Province of China", "Zambia", "Netherlands", "Saint Martin (French part)", "Tajikistan", "Zimbabwe")

rplcList = Array("434", "540", "670", "834", "438", "554", "666", "764", "440", "558", "882", "626", "442", _
"562", "674", "768", "446", "566", "678", "772", "807", "570", "682", "776", "450", "574", "686", "780", "454", _
"580", "688", "788", "458", "578", "690", "792", "462", "512", "694", "795", "466", "586", "702", "796", "470", _
"585", "534", "798", "584", "275", "703", "800", "474", "591", "705", "804", "478", "598", "90", "784", "480", _
"600", "706", "826", "175", "604", "710", "840", "484", "608", "239", "581", "583", "612", "728", "999", "498", _
"616", "724", "858", "492", "620", "144", "860", "496", "630", "654", "548", "499", "634", "736", "862", "500", _
"638", "740", "704", "504", "642", "744", "92", "104", "643", "748", "850", "508", "646", "752", "876", "516", _
"652", "756", "732", "520", "659", "760", "887", "524", "662", "158", "894", "528", "663", "762", "716")
```

Once that is complete then you can iterate by Columns not sheets with a little altering of the code:

```
For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
    'Loop through each COLUMN in ActiveSheet
      For Each col In ActiveSheet.Columns
      If col.Address <> "$H:$H" Then
        col.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
          LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        End If
      Next col
Next x
```